# Applying snap.js to my main content wrapper seems to break *some* of my jQuery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, snap.js

I'm using snap.js which enables you to slide your main content `div` over using css3 and javascript, revealing a menu underneath.

The problem I am having is that when I apply the class `snap-content`, which tells snap.js which `div` to slide, that being my main site wrapper, the elements relying on jQuery for their sizing behave unexpectedly.

**Here's my situation.**

I'm using jQuery to make an element fixed when scrolling past a certain point:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 140) {
            if ($("#mainMenu").css('position') !== 'fixed') {
                $("#mainMenu").css("position", "fixed");
            }
        } else {
            if ($("#mainMenu").css('position') !== 'static') {
                $("#mainMenu").css("position", "static");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

When using snap.js I had to change `$(window).scroll` to `$('#wrapper').scroll` because the wrapper is now the scrollable content. I believe this could have something to do with my problem.

When the menu becomes fixed I use some jQuery to keep it the same width as the container it was inside before it became fixed:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(window).resize(_.debounce(function () {
        var elementWidth = $('#sidebarWrapper').width();
        $('#mainMenu').css('width', elementWidth + 'px');
    }, 10));
});
```

This all works fine before I add the class `snap-content`, and I can resize the browser without any problems.

**When the class is added the sizing no longer works.**

There are other functions to do with sizing that start to act unexpectedly too but this is just an example.

I assumed it might be something clashing with my jQuery but I'm using `jQuery(function($)` so that should stop that right?

[snap.js](https://github.com/jakiestfu/Snap.js/)

Comment: I'm having similar issues.  Did you get it to work?

Comment: @ltrainpr afraid not I'm afraid, I ditched it completely.

Answer (score 0):

instead of adding the event to the window scroll add it to the snapcontent since you are scrolling on the snapcontent div instead of the window