# How to combine slide-in panels with sticky header?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position, css-transforms

I'm currently working on a CSS-based 3-column layout that has the following requirements:

- On the desktop…

  - …all columns are shown.
- On mobile devices…

  - …only the middle column is shown.
  - …the left column can slide in from the left, triggered by a swipe or a tap on a button.
  - …the right column can slide in from the right, triggered by a swipe or a tap on a button.
- Independent of the device…

  - …the middle column contains three rows: The main header, a sub header, and the actual content.
  - …the main header scrolls away when scrolling down.
  - …the subheader is sticky on the top of the screen when scrolling down.

Now I tried to implement this:

- Creating a 3-column layout and hiding the left and right columns is easy, using Bootstrap.
- Having three rows in the middle column is easy, too.
- To make the subheader sticky, I have two options:

  - Use `position: sticky` (best solution in technical terms, but not supported by any browser).
  - Use a script, attach to the `scroll` event and change to `position: fixed` on demand. This is what Bootstrap offers OOTB with its `affix` plugin. Using this plugin, it's an easy task, too.
- Creating two sidebars and sliding them in is easy as well, using something such as [Snap.js](https://github.com/jakiestfu/Snap.js/).

Problems start when I want to combine the sticky subheader with the sliding sidebars: The `affix` plugin simply stops working, and the subheader is not sticky any more. Basically, the problem comes down to issues with CSS `transform` and `position: fixed`, see [Eric Meyer's awesome blog post on this](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2011/09/12/un-fixing-fixed-elements-with-css-transforms/) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10814178/css-performance-relative-to-translatez0/10814448#10814448).

One option to solve this could be to put the headers above the area where the sidebars slide in, so that they are not affected, but this is not what I want: I want the sidebar to push away *everything*.

How can I solve this? Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this post:
[Applying snap.js to my main content wrapper seems to break *some* of my jQuery functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20792655/applying-snap-js-to-my-main-content-wrapper-seems-to-break-some-of-my-jquery-f)

Bootstraps affix.js listens to the $(window).on('scroll'... event. Snap.js seems to change the scrollable element from the "window" element to the element where you added the "snap-content" class. I dont see any other solution as to write the sticky functionality provided by bootstrap yourself.

Use this as a reference. Based on your current scroll position (in pixels) you can add css attributes or even whole css classes to the element you want to make sticky:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$('.snap-content').scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 140) {
        if ($("#navbar").css('position') !== 'fixed') {
            $("#navbar").css("position", "fixed");
        }
    } else {
        if ($("#navbar").css('position') !== 'static') {
            $("#navbar").css("position", "static");
        }
    }
});
```

});

Comment: Would've been nice to make it work without any custom code, but nevertheless, this approach works :-)